# Extracting and matching columns in text file

Tags: perl, awk, cut

I have a text file with the following structure. I want to remove first part before comma and keep rest and then match them to the 2nd column and put them in individual rows.

INPUT:

```
A,B,C       London
G,L,K,I     Berlin
Q,O,M,J     Madrid
```

I want a output like this:

OUTPUT:

```
B  London
C  London
L  Berlin
K  Berlin
I  Berlin
O  Madrid
M  Madrid
J  Madrid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a way with awk:

```
$ awk '{n=split($1, a, ","); for (i=2; i<=n; i++) print a[i], $NF}' file
B London
C London
L Berlin
K Berlin
I Berlin
O Madrid
M Madrid
J Madrid
```

#### Explanation

- `n=split($1, a, ",")` slices the first field into pieces based on comma as delimiter. `split` returns the number of slices and we store that.
- `for (i=2; i<=n; i++) print a[i], $NF` we then loop through all these slices, starting from the 2nd one, printing each one together with the last field (city name).

Comment: thanks.It worked. Can you refer me a online page where I can learn a bit more about Awk and Sed?

Comment: @palc nice to read that. I am a bit fan of this page about idiomatic awk: http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/  To start it is also good to read http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html For `sed` I don't have any special suggestion, maybe `man sed` and google a bit for something else. Finally, trying to solve questions in [so] helps a lot!

Answer (score 3):

A Perl way

```
perl -aF[\\s,]+ -nE'say "$_ $F[-1]" for @F[1..$#F-1]' myfile
```

**output**

```
B London
C London
L Berlin
K Berlin
I Berlin
O Madrid
M Madrid
J Madrid
```

Comment: `-F[\s,]+` Didn't work. `perl -aF',|\s+' -nE '$v = pop @F; shift @F; say "$_ $v" for @F'  file` does the trick, I don't know why though.

Comment: @Tiago: `-a` implies `-n`. You should use `-aF[\s,]+`, not `-F[\s,]+`

Comment: @fedorqui: Sorry, I minsunderstood. Fixed.

Comment: sorry to bother you but do you why is that happening: paste.ubuntu.com/7826816. `-aF'[\s,]+'` (quoted) works though.

Comment: @Tiago: My guess is that the backslash isn't getting through the shell. Try `-aF[\\s,]+`

Comment: Good guess! why didn't you have to do that in your system? which shell are you using?

Comment: BTW +1 for the explanation :)

Comment: @Tiago: I was using a Windows machine at the time, which requires its parameters to be quoted differently. I converted it to Linux style manually but couldn't test it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `perl` tag:

```
perl -alne '$F[0]=~s/^.*?,//g; @a=split /,/,$F[0]; map { print "$_ $F[1]" } @a' file 
B London
C London
L Berlin
K Berlin
I Berlin
O Madrid
M Madrid
J Madrid
```

Explanation:

1. `-a` Splits fields into array `@F`
2. `-l` prints `\n` after every print statement
3. `-n` Loops trough file
4. `$F[0]=~s/^.*?,//g;` Removes anything between begging of string
   and `,` for position 0 of array @F
5. `@a=split /,/,$F[0];` Creates array `@a`
6. `map { print "$_ $F[1]" } @a` could also be written as `foreach(@a){print "$_ $F[1]"}`

Shorter version using `shift`:

```
perl -alne '@a=split /,/,$F[0]; shift @a; print "$_ $F[1]" for @a' file
```

Comment: `map { print "$_ $F[1]" } @a` is much better written as `print "$_ $F[1]" for @a`

Comment: @Borodin thanks for that I didn't know was possible.